# How to remove all empty tag with conditons in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, tags, conditional-statements, xml-namespaces

I want to remove empty tags with exception.
I made an XSL to remove all empty tags with exception. Following the XSL below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:preserve-space elements="cEAN"/ priority="1">
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*[not(@*) and not(*) and (not(text()) or .=-1)]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When the XML following the rules below, it's working fine,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <NFe xmlns:n0="http://mynamespace">
     <cProd>0000000000001</cProd>
     <cEAN> </cEAN>
     <xProd>ARV NAT</xProd>
     <NCM>01000</NCM>
     <CFOP>9999</CFOP>
     </uCom>
 </Nfe>
```

The transformation XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NFe xmlns:n0="http://mynamespace">
  <cProd>0000000000001</cProd>
  <cEAN />
  <xProd>ARV NAT</xProd>
  <NCM>01000</NCM>
  <CFOP>9999</CFOP>
</NFe>
```

But when the XML following the rules below, Isn't work.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <NFe xmlns:n0="http://mynamespace">
     <cProd>0000000000001</cProd>
     <cEAN/>
     <xProd>ARV NAT</xProd>
     <NCM>01000</NCM>
     <CFOP>999</CFOP>
     <uCom/>
  </Nfe>
```

The transformation XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NFe xmlns:n0="http://mynamespace">
   <cProd>0000000000001</cProd>
   <xProd>ARV NAT</xProd>
   <NCM>01000</NCM>
   <CFOP>9999</CFOP>
</NFe>
```

The tag cEAN is not preserved and it's remove all empty tags.

Someone could help me?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why should the empty `<cEAN/>` tag **not** be removed? You say "*I made an XSL to remove all empty tags with exception*". I don't see that exception. Your 2nd template removes **all** empty tags **and** also tags whose only content is "-1".

Comment: That's obviously going to remove `cEAN` and and `uCOm`. They have no attributes AND no child nodes AND no text.. therefore all three conditions in your 'and' condition are true, and it will match. You probably just need to review the logic of that expression.

Comment: I'm new on XSL, I would like to remove all blank tag except <cEAN> Do you know how i could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to correct your XMLs to be valid. I hope, that you meant `<cEAN/>` by `</cEAN>` as I don't see any start tag for that.
And there can be no `@priority` in `xsl:preserve-space` element.

If my assumptions are correct, it is the expected behavior.
An element like following means that `cEAN` has a text node with value as a space().

```
<cEAN> </cEAN>
```

And,

```
<cEAN/>
```

means that the element `cEAN` is having a null value(no text node, no child element) in it. And `<cEAN/>` is same as `<cEAN></cEAN>`.

The template in your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(@*) and not(*) and (not(text()) or .=-1)]"/>
```

matches `<cEAN/>` and hence is omitted in the output as the template does nothing.

To remove all empty elements except `cEAN` elements, you can use the following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*[. = '' and not(self::cEAN)]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If your input is following XML:

```
<NFe>
    <cEAN/>
    <CFOP>9999</CFOP>
    <empty/>
</NFe>
```

The output would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NFe>
   <cEAN/>
   <CFOP>9999</CFOP>
</NFe>
```

Comment: Hi... First of all thanks for your answer.  
I'm new on XSL, I would like to remove all blank tag but with an exception to the tag <cEAN> Do you know how i could do this? –